# How to solve quadratic equations in C, using 3 coefficients?

Tags: c, loops

My professor told us to write a c program which solves quadratic equations but he added that at the start he wants us to define 4 sets of 3  coefficients for each a, b and c. So in other words I have to define 4 sets of 3 different coefficients for each a, b, and c and once the program solves the equation for the 1st set of 3 coefficients for a,b and c its to proceed and solve the next set of 3 defined coefficients until all 4 sets are solved.

I am able to write a program that solves the quadratic equation by defining each a,b and c coefficient individual using scanf. Can you please help, as I can't find the answer anywhere?

Thats what I have written so far, its pretty simple but it works. I'm in an engineering course and we only have 2hrs a week of labs which dont reflect the lectures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int as[4], bs[4], cs[4];
int a, b, c;
double root1,root2,discriminant, realpart, imaginarypart;
int main ()
{ 
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter how many coefficents do you want to eneter : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter you coefficents for a,b and c for set %d : \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d %d %d",&as[i],&bs[i],&cs[i]);
        a = as[i];
        b = bs[i];
        c = cs[i] ;
    }
    printf("a = %d %d %d\n", as[0], as[1], as[2]);
    printf("b = %d %d %d\n", bs[0], bs[1], bs[2]);
    printf("c = %d %d %d\n", cs[0], cs[1], cs[2]);

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
    discriminant = (b*b - 4*a*c);
    root1 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    root2 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);



    if (discriminant > 0 )
    {
    printf("Your set %d of roots is : \nroot1 = %lf\nroot2 = %lf\n", i+1,root1, root2); 
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0)  
    {
        printf("Your set %d of roots is : \nroot1 = root2 = %lf\n",i+1,root1);
    }
    else 
    {
        realpart = -b/(2*a);
        imaginarypart = sqrt(-discriminant)/(2*a);
        printf("Your set %d of roots is :\nroot1 = %lf + %lfi\nroot2 = %lf - %lfi\n",i+1,realpart, imaginarypart, realpart, imaginarypart);
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it's an assignment, so the whole point is you're meant to come to the answer yourself. If you try, and get stuck on one particular error, we will help, but we aren't here to write your code for you.

Comment: He doesn't ask for a *complete code* as he told that he is *able* to write a program that solves the quadratic equation. He has only a *particular problem* with defining *more than 1 set of coefficients* `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: @MarianD: unless we can see some code written by a question asker, it is generally a good idea for readers to assume that nothing has been done. The making of and demonstration of effort is a pre-requisite here. (It is hard to make a judgement call in edge cases, but equally posters need to know we have homework cheats here every day, which means that genuine posters need to differentiate their material from the lazy ones).

Comment: I have to agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix 2 things: *defining* 4 sets and *reading them from input* (as I understood from your "using `scanf`").

(Reading them from input makes no problem as new read values overwrite old.)

*Defining* 4 sets in advance may be simply done by *arrays*:

```
float as[4], bs[4], cs[4];        // as[0], bs[0], cs[0] is the 1st set, etc.
float a    , b    , c    ;

// Assigning values to sets: as[0] = ...; bs[0] = ..., cs[0] = ...;
                             as[1] = ...; bs[1] = ..., cs[1] = ...;
                             ......................................
                             ......................................

//  or initialize them directly in the previous declaration, e.g. 
//                           float as[] = {1,  4, -2,  3},
//                                 bs[] = {0,  5,  1, -1}, 
//                                 cs[] = {2, -4,  1,  2}; 

for (int i; i < 4; ++i)
{
    a = a[i];
    b = b[i];
    c = c[i];
    // Code (or a function call) for computing and printing result(s) from a, b, c
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I was thinking of using arrays but don't have great experience with them, but this helps a lot.